# Python dictionary view

Tags: python, dictionary

Is a dictionary the right type for data where I want to look up entries based on an index, e.g.

```
dictlist = {}  
dictlist['itemid' + '1'] = {'name':'AAA', 'class':'Class1', 'nonstandard':'whatever'}  
dictlist['itemid' + '2'] = {'name':'BBB', 'class':'Class2', 'maynotbehere':'optional'}  
dictlist['itemid' + '3'] = {'name':'CCC', 'class':'Class3', 'regular':'or not'}
```

I can now address a specific item, e.g.

```
finditem='itemid2'  
dictitem = {}  
try:  
   dictitem[finditem] = dictlist[finditem]  
   print dictitem  
except KeyError:  
   print "Nothing there"
```

Is that the right way to create such a lookup table in python?

If I now wanted to print the data, but only the Item ID, and an associated dictionary with only name and class "properties", how can I do that?

I am looking for something that will create a new dictionary by copying the desired properties only, or else present a limited view of the existing dictionary, as if the unspecified properties were not there. So for example

```
view(dictlist, 'name', 'class')
```

will return a dictionary that displays a restricted view of the list, showing only the name and class keys. I have tried

```
view = {}
for item in dictlist:
   view[item] = {dictlist[item]['name'], dictlist[item]['class']}

print view
```

Which returns

```
{'itemid1': set(['AAA', 'Class1']), 'itemid3': set(['Class3', 'CCC']), 'itemid2': set(['Class2', 'BBB'])}
```

Instead of

```
{'itemid1': {'name':'AAA', 'class':'Class1'}, 'itemid3': {'name':'CCC', 'class':'Class3'}, 'itemid2': {'name':'BBB', 'class':'Class2'}  }
```

Comment: That should be `except KeyError:`, and it's not clear why you're putting `dictlist[finditem]` into a new dictionary (or calling a dictionary of dictionaries `dictlist`), but the approach is generally fine. `view` would be easy enough to write, I suggest you learn a bit more about Python's data structures and have a go yourself.

Comment: I'm calling it a dictlist because I'm using it as a list which contains a dictionary at each "index"

Comment: I want to return a dictionary (with the same subscript) because I am probably going to add more data to the resulting data structure later on.

Comment: I fixed the Exception Handler.  I guess it is bad to "handle" unexpected exceptions the wrong way.

Comment: It's not good practice to put a bare `except` - see e.g. http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `{'foo', 'bar'}` is a *set literal*, **not** a *dictionary literal*, as it does not have the `key: value` syntax required for a dictionary:

```
>>> type({'foo', 'bar'})
<class 'set'>
>>> type({'foo': 'bar'})
<class 'dict'>
```

You need to be more careful with your syntax generally; I have no idea what the random closing square brackets `]` are doing in the output you claim you want, and it's missing a closing brace `}`.

You could extend your current code to do keys *and* values as follows:

```
for item in dictlist:
   view[item] = {'name': dictlist[item]['name'], 
                 'class': dictlist[item]['class']}
```

but a more generic function would look like:

```
def view(dictlist, *keys):
    output = {}
    for item in dictlist:
        output[item] = {}
        for key in keys:
            output[item][key] = dictlist[item].get(key)
    return output
```

note the use of `dict.get` to handle missing keys gracefully:

```
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> d.get('foo') 
'bar' # returns the value if key present, or
>>> d.get('baz') 
>>> # returns None by default
```

or, using a *"dictionary comprehension"*:

```
def view(dictlist, *keys):
    return {k1: {k2: v2 for k2, v2 in v1.items() if k2 in keys}
            for k1, v1 in dictlist.items()}
```

*(This will exclude missing keys from the output, whereas the previous code will include them with `None` value - which is preferable will depend on your use case.)*

Note the use of `*keys` to take an arbitrary number of positional arguments:

```
>>> def test(d, *keys):
    print(keys)


>>> test({}, "foo", "bar", "baz")
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```